# import scss in a react component on SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, sass

I'm working on a skeleton to have (for myself or whoever wants it) with webpack react express and ssr (server side rendering).

I'm having an issue where i cant import scss in react components.

For some reason I can import them in the files where I do `ReactDOM.hydrate`

I've tried hundreds of different webpack configurations, and also tried generating a single css file, which I wasn't able to also.

**scss config**

```
{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }
```

package.json dependencies:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"autoprefixer": "^9.4.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"css-loader": "^2.1.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"isomorphic-style-loader": "^4.0.0",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"nodemon": "^1.18.9",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"style-loader": "^0.23.1",
"url-loader": "^1.1.2",
"webpack": "^4.28.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0"
```

Simple hydrate file where I can require scss:

```
require('./index.scss');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const Search = require('./Search');

ReactDOM.hydrate(<Search text={window.__INITIAL__.text} />, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

same component passed to hydrate where i cannot add the require cause it makes webpack compilation break.

```
const React = require('react')
const Nav = require('../../components/nav/Nav.js')

class Search extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        text: props.text || null,
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id="main">
            <Nav />
            <p>{this.state.text}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
}

module.exports = Search;
```

I'm trying to get the `require or import` to work inside each component, but so far wasn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this webpack config to add sass in your ssr and react.

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const isDevelopment = true;

module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'client',
    target: 'web',
    entry: './client.jsx',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
      filename: 'client.js',
      publicPath: '/static/',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                },
                sourceMap: isDevelopment,
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'server',
    target: 'node',
    entry: './server.jsx',
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
      filename: 'server.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      publicPath: '/static/',
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules\/)/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'isomorphic-style-loader',
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: {
                  localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                },
                sourceMap: isDevelopment,
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  }
];
```

I set up a boilerplate and you can use it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68600509/6200607